# Getting values in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the column that has the same Colour and First Name because the arrays are not equal in both of them. 
I said will mix them using itertools product.

```
a=[['Mike' 'Steve' 'Blue'],['Mike' 'Chi' 'A2'],['Liz' 'Bill 'A1'],['Mike' 'Smith' 'C1'],['Billy' 'Kaphle' A1']]
b=[[['Mike' 'Steve' 'A1],['Mike' 'Chi' 'F'],['Mike' 'Kaphle' 'Blue],['Liz' 'Bill 'B1'],['Mike' 'Smith' 'D'],['Raj' 'Sigs' Orange']]

Score1=a[:,2]
Score2=b[:,2]
Name1=a[:,0]
Name1=a[:,0]

good=[]
companies = (itertools.product(score1,score2))
for c in companies:
     if c[0]==c[1]:
         if Name2 == Name2:
             good.append(a)
             good.append(b)
```

So basically I should be having ['Mike' 'Steve' 'Blue']
                                ['Mike' 'Kaphle' 'Blue]
because they both have the same 2 column and first column

Comment: `a[:,2]` - you can't index a list with a tuple

Comment: `Name2` is not defined and you access it inside the loop without doing any changes or indexing. So the if statement is either always `true` or `false`

Comment: Your code is broken, it gives syntax error on your first line.